# C# Equivalent of %0 in batch

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line-arguments

Ok, within a batch file using `%0` will return the location and name of the batch file. E.g.

```
call %0 "Arguments"
```

which would cause the batch file to call itself with specified arguments. Though my requirement is a bit different, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in C#. Basically, I want the name of the executable the user ran to start my program.

In batch this is used incase the user renames the program, but since C# is object-orientated there would be no need for this. Then to there still must be some old way to do this.

Thanks in advance, Mona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns an array the different command line arguments, corresponding to `%0`, `%1`,... in batch.

So you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` the get the started process.

(If I remember correctly, there is one gotcha with this technique: This can be the 8.3 name `MYAPPL~1.EXE` instead of the full name depending on how the program was started. Luckily those are used very rarely nowadays)

Comment: Wait, so if I exclude `string[] args` from `Main` I can still access and arguments the user inputs?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK this equivalent to `args` on `Main`.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname.aspx)

> The friendly name of the default application domain is the file name
>   of the process executable. For example, if the executable used to
>   start the process is "c:\MyAppDirectory\MyAssembly.exe", the friendly
>   name of the default application domain is "MyAssembly.exe".

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

I think it answers this question:

> I want the name of the executable the user ran to start my program.

Comment: Minor technicality: what if the code executing this line isn't running in the default application domain, but in a custom app domain with a name like "Foo"? (I did not down vote this answer.)

Comment: Thanks worked great, but CodeslnChaos worked out better for me.

Comment: The `FriendlyName` can be chosen by the host and isn't necessarily the path to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` in your `Main`.

Comment: That gives the path to the executing assembly (possibly a class library), not the path to the originally launched process. So it's not equivalent to `%0`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Mona said "I want the name of the executable the user ran to start my program", so executing assembly is the executable itself in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not if you put this in a class library. In that case this returns a `.dll` not the `.exe`.